# How to prevent this SQL script from entering into an infinite loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables with columns

- Users: id, linkedinID, stackoverflowId, bitbucketid, bitbucketid, githubid
- Resumes: id, userid, linkedId, stackoverflowId, bitbucketid, bitbucketid, githubid, excludeprofile (boolean type)

I want to transfer all id's (userId, linkedIn etc) to the `users` table columns and if there not a single Id among all is present in resume table then store true in excludeprofile.

I have written the following script for this

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @userId Int
DECLARE @linkedIn varchar(max)
DECLARE @StackOverflow varchar(max)
DECLARE @HackerRank varchar(max)
DECLARE @Bitbucket varchar(max)
DECLARE @Github varchar(max)
DECLARE @x int

SET @x = 0

WHILE @x <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Users 
                   ORDER BY Id OFFSET @x ROWS   
                               FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
    BEGIN
        SET @userId = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Users)
        SET @x = @x + 1;
    END

    IF (@userId <> NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT LinkedInProfile FROM Resumes WHERE Resumes.UserId = @userId)
        BEGIN
            SET @linkedIn = (SELECT LinkedInProfile FROM Resumes WHERE Resumes.UserId = @userId)
        END 

    if exists(select Github from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    begin
    set @Github =(select Github from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    end
    if exists(select Bitbucket from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    begin
    set @Bitbucket =(select Bitbucket from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    end
    if exists(select HackerRank from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    begin
    set @HackerRank =(select HackerRank from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    end
    if exists(select StackOverflow  from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    begin
    set @StackOverflow =(select StackOverflow from Resumes where Resumes.UserId=@userId)
    end
    end
END

    if(@linkedIn!=null)
    begin
    update Users set LinkedInProfile=@linkedIn
    where Users.Id = @userId;
    end
    if(@linkedIn <> null or @Bitbucket <> null or @Github = null or @StackOverflow = null or @HackerRank = null)
    begin
    update Resumes set ExcludeProfiles=0
    where Resumes.UserId = @userId;
    end
    if(@linkedIn = null and @Bitbucket = null and @Github = null and @StackOverflow = null and @HackerRank = null)
    begin
    update Resumes set ExcludeProfiles=0
    where Resumes.UserId = @userId;
    end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I think the loop is infinite the because the execution did not stop.

Comment: This looks more like SQL Server, not MySQL. What RDBMS are you really using here? PLease retag that RDBMS, and only that RDBMS, What is the problem you're having? What is your question? Why are you using a `WHILE`, when you're writing SQL, not C#?

Comment: @Larnu I want to transfer the data from resume table to user table, and I am using while loop because this will be for multiple users

Comment: You *don't* need cursors or loops with SQL. It's a set-based language. You can write a *single* INSERT or UPDATE to update a target table with values from a source table, eg `INSERT target (a,b,c) SELECT source.a,source.b,source c from Source` or `update target set a=source.a from target inner join source on target.ID=source.ID`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using variables because I have to write it into the generalized way and  it should be a script.

Comment: You don't need them for either. A script is a file containing T-SQL commands, one of which is `UPDATE`. You don't need that loop. A single `UPDATE` would work and update all 3 fields at once. You wouldn't need the null checks either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone in the comments already pointed out: you do not need a `WHILE` loop or a cursor for these kinds of operations.

**Create target tables**

```
declare @User table
(
    Id int,    --User
    LI_id int, --LinkedIn
    SO_id int, --StackOverflow
    BB_id int, --BitBucket
    GH_id int  --GitHub
);

declare @Resume table
(
    Id int,
    Us_id int, --User (1*)
    LI_id int, --LinkedIn (2*)
    SO_id int, --StackOveflow (3*)
    BB_id int, --BitBucket (4*)
    GH_id int, --GitHub (5*)
    Excl bit   --ExcludeProfile
);
```

**Solution 1**

Mark *Resume* rows as not excluded by default (`Excl = 0`). The proper way to do this would be with a [column default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns) in the table definition.

```
insert into @Resume (Id, Us_id, LI_id, SO_id, BB_id, GH_id, Excl) values
(1,  101,  201,  301,  401,  501, 0),
(2,  102, null,  302,  402,  502, 0),
(3,  103,  203,  303,  403,  503, 0),
(4, null, null, null, null, null, 0); --resume without id's
```

The solution can then be achieved with two queries. If you want to avoid that one query successfully runs without the other, then you should add a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql) around them.

1. Copy the valid rows from *Resume* to *User*.
2. Mark all invalid rows from *Resume* as excluded.

Implementation:

```
insert into @User (Id, LI_id, SO_id, BB_id, GH_id)
select Us_id, LI_id, SO_id, BB_id, GH_id
from @Resume
where not (     Us_id is null
            and LI_id is null
            and SO_id is null
            and BB_id is null
            and GH_id is null);

update @Resume
set Excl = 1
where Us_id is null
  and LI_id is null
  and SO_id is null
  and BB_id is null
  and GH_id is null;
```

**Solution 2**

An alternative would be to mark *Resume* rows with an excluded user by default (`Excl = 1`). Again, you can use [column default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns) for this.

```
insert into @Resume (Id, Us_id, LI_id, SO_id, BB_id, GH_id, Excl) values
(1,  101,  201,  301,  401,  501, 1),
(2,  102, null,  302,  402,  502, 1),
(3,  103,  203,  303,  403,  503, 1),
(4, null, null, null, null, null, 1); --resume without id's
```

With this approach it is now possible to copy (insert) and update the valid *Resume* rows in one single query using the [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sq) clause. This also means that a transaction is now not required, because the query is now a single operation.

```
update r
set r.Excl = 0
output  inserted.Us_id,
        inserted.LI_id,
        inserted.SO_id,
        inserted.BB_id,
        inserted.GH_id
into @User
from @Resume r
where not (     r.Us_id is null
            and r.LI_id is null
            and r.SO_id is null
            and r.BB_id is null
            and r.GH_id is null);
```

**Result**

The output is the same for both solutions.

```
select * from @resume;

Id          Us_id       LI_id       SO_id       BB_id       GH_id       Excl
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----
1           101         201         301         401         501         0
2           102         NULL        302         402         502         0
3           103         203         303         403         503         0
4           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        1


select * from @user;

Id          LI_id       SO_id       BB_id       GH_id
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
101         201         301         401         501
102         NULL        302         402         502
103         203         303         403         503
```